# Using jquery/javascript to return unencoded value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a list of  tags with content from returned json but I want to append the special character `&#10006`(✖) to each item.

My jQuery code as is listed:

```js
$("span />", {text: (value["id"] + "&#10006"}).appendTo("#divmyList");
```

Somehow &#10006 keeps getting encoded and all I see is literally &#10006 and not the "x".

How do you specify when it is being passed into the text value in jQuery that this is a literal value and not to be HTML encoded?

Comment: are you putting a semicolon at the end of `&#10006`?

Comment: Use `html` instead of `text`. Or even better just pass `"\u2716"`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method instead of `text` property

```
$("<span />").html("&#10006").appendTo("#divmyList");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/19760d1k/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use HTML-entitities in plain [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). Just use an unicode escape sequence:

```
$("<span />", {text: value["id"] + "\u2716"}).appendTo("#divmyList");
```